# How can I take multiple values from a single command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot that returns the image of a card when searched for with a bot command. I was able to make a command to get a single card, but I would like to be able to search for multiple cards with one command. How can I do this?

Here is my code for the single search:

```
@bot.command(brief = "Fetch a card.", description = "Use this command to search for a card.")
async def card(ctx, *, search):
    try:
        result = scrython.cards.Named(fuzzy=search)

    except scrython.ScryfallError as e:
        error = (str(e.error_details['details']))
        await ctx.send(error)

    else:
        result = result.image_uris(image_type = 'large')
        await ctx.send(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

discord.py supports the greedy positional argument syntax (VAR_POSITIONAL) with `*searches`, then add `require_var_positional=True` to specify that the user needs to enter at least one search.

```
@bot.command(require_var_positional=True)
async def card(ctx, *searches):
    ... # searches will be a tuple of search terms
```

Example (prefix `!`):

- `!card first` then `searches = ('first', )`
- `!card first second` then `searches = ('first', 'second')`
- `!card` errors
- `!card one "two words" "three words here"` then `searches = ('one', 'two words', 'three words here')`

Comment: This works great! Is there a way i could separate the card names in the command with commas and not have to use quotation marks?

Comment: @Cookiejaguar You'll need to make a custom converter for that, sadly discord.py only parses quotation marks.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you anyways.